# Handling pop-up window Metamask extension - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, metamask

I have been trying to find out how to call upon a pop-up window from an extension, in this case 'Metamask'.
Is there a way to call upon the elements inside the pop-up?

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T8eh.png)

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/

Used the official website to search for codes, but cannot find something that is able to do so.

Thanks in advance!

Tried accessing the pop-up window to find xpath elements, but can't be found.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.